# What does it mean when a value is passed through a next function?

Tags: node.js, express

I have been looking through some code online for building a React to-do app that uses an Express backend. The link to the website is [here](https://www.devsurvival.com/todo-app-react-backend/), and I came across this part of the code:

```
app.get("/todos", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const todos = await db.Todo.find({});
    return success(res, todos);
  } catch (err) {
    next({ status: 400, message: "failed to get todos" });
  }
});
```

I know that the next function is a function that passes the operation of the current middleware function that it is in to the next middleware function of the same route. However, sources online just use the simple "next()" function, but this code has a value, an object, that is passed into the next function.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### this code has a value, an object, that is passed into the next function. What does this mean?

**Ans:** This means that you are passing an object as a parameter to the next middleware function.

```js
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  return res.status(err.status || 400).json({
    status: err.status || 400,
    message: err.message || "there was an error processing request"
  });
});
```

Here **err** parameter is the object that you have passed.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a naming convention in Node.js, used to control the next matching route.

This stuff is frequently found, also very handy, and mostly used in access checks or wildcard routes. (*/user/:id*)

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    // this route requires auth, check if logged in. If not, redirect to login.
    if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
      next({
        path: `/${ViewName.UserLogin}`,
        query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
      });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }
```

Comment: If it's a naming convention that's used to control the next matching route, what is the "status" and "message" values in my example doing?

Comment: The "status" and "message" in your example is the request object, setting a response code in "status" and its message in "message". So, next(), will stil forward you to the route _but_ giving you this response object which will prevent the user from seeing the routes content

Answer (score 0):

From the express documentation:

> Starting with Express 5, middleware functions that return a Promise will call next(value) when they reject or throw an error. next will be called with either the rejected value or the thrown Error.

So it seems to me like the value inside the next() function is the return value that is sent to the next callback. Often you don't want to send a custom value and just go to the next middleware function, however in this case they apparently wanted to set the error message inside the next() function and thus override any default values.

Hope this helps